# Is there a reduced form of the dot product in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find a numpy operation that gives me the scalar products between all vectors of a 2d array at index i of a 3d array and the vector at index i of a 2d array. Let me give you an example to explain what I am thinking of:

```
x = np.array([[[1,2,3],
              [2,3,4]],
             
             [[11,12,13],
              [12,13,14]]])

y = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [2,2,2]])



np.?operation?(x,y.T)

output:
[[[1 *1 + 1 *2 + 1 *3], 
  [1 *2 + 1 *3 + 1 *4]],

 [[2 *11 + 2 *12 + 2 *13], 
  [2 *12 + 2* 13 + 2 *14]]]

= [[[6], 
    [9]],

   [[72], 
    [78]]]
```

As you can see, I am basically looking for a reduced dot product operation. The dot product of x and y would yield the following:

```
np.dot(x, y.T)

output:
[[[ 6 12]
  [ 9 18]]

 [[36 72]
  [39 78]]]
```

I have also tried np.tensordot(x,y,axis) but I were not able to figure which tuples I should put for -axis-.

Also, this is my first question. So please, instead of downvoting my question, tell me what I can improve next time. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know numpy very well but this looks like a very specific operation, so you can probably just do your own function with a loop.